# Download Every Attachment from Gmail

Tags: gmail, gmail-search

So I've been working at a place for a while now and am quitting next week. I basically need to download every attachment from every email that has been sent or received. Is there any way to do so?

Answer (score 1):

1. Download all your emails via https://takeout.google.com/
2. Extract all attachments from the downloaded archive.